# JAVA. GSON. How to pass the argument to toJson()?

Tags: java, gson

I have class WorldModel and it has ArrayList field countries, I need to serialize json with not all countries but only requested ones by client.

Is there any way to pass the argument in toJson() function? Some array or list?
To serialize only fields that consider to the condition.

**EDIT:** added the use case code:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/getWorldModel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getInfrastructure(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "countries", required = true) String countries) {

    Gson jsonCTS = jsonBuilder.fromWorldModelToJson();
    String jCTS = jsonCTS.toJson(worldModel);

    return jCTS;
}
```

I serialize th WorldModel worldModel object which has many countries, but I need only some of them according to client's request.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This would be a very good time to read through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The details provided are extremely thin and open to a lots of different interpretations. After reading through that link edit the question with a properly detailed problem description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer to my question by myself.
The solution is pretty simple.

I created the special method filter which create a temporal duplicate of the object with propper fields value. So I serialize this object instead of the original one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude some fields of object you can do it by this code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                //your condition
                return f.getName().equal("test");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> aClass) {
                return false;
            }
        })
        .create();
```

If you want to exclude some elements of the list you can simply edit your list by `list.remove("test")` and then use the same object.

Comment: it looks good but how can I pass the f attribute to toJson() function? Or I should recreat the GsonBuilder each time?

Comment: Where are you using gson? You can use gson for every object like this: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); gson.toJson(object). You can set GsonBuilder once somewhere(like singleton pattern or static object) and get that for every usage.

Comment: Oh! I have invented the solution... I think there will be the most easy way just to create another worldModel object with cutted off the useless data and serialize this one.

Comment: You can update your list and remove elements from it by list.removeAll(countries) and use the same WorldModel and no need of the new object.

Comment: my app's logic uses this variable as global for other objects, so I can't do this but thank you anyway for your help. It was very useful!